Como deixar valor Zero quando está vazio para determinado campo na Matriz do Power Bi?
Boa Noite Pessoal,
Tenho um visual matriz no power bi, em linhas tenho Fornecedor/Departamento/Seção/Produto em valores tenho Caixa Geral |  TIPO 1  |   TIPO 13, quando a coluna nao teve a qtde fica vazio, mas preciso que fique com Zero. Quando utilizo esse codigo para deixar com zero, meu filtro de segmentação não funciona, traz os mesmos produtos para os fornecedores diferentes. Só funciona se eu deixar a matriz só com fornecedor.
TIPO 1 = 
IF(
    ISBLANK(
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(VENDAS[QT_UNT]),
            VENDAS[CODTIPO] = 1
        )
    ),
    0,
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(VENDAS[QT_UNT]),
        VENDAS[CODTIPO] = 1
    )
)

Segue print da matriz

O problema que você está enfrentando ocorre porque o CALCULATE com uma condição específica (no seu caso, VENDAS[CODTIPO] = 1) pode estar alterando o contexto de filtro da matriz, fazendo com que o filtro de segmentação não funcione corretamente.
Para resolver esse problema, você pode tentar usar a função COALESCE, que retorna o primeiro valor não nulo (nesse caso, substituindo os valores em branco por zero), em vez de manipular diretamente os valores com IF. Isso preservará o contexto de filtro e permitirá que a segmentação funcione corretamente.
Segue print cod digitado tenta esse
TIPO 1 =
COALESCE(
CALCULATE(
SUM(VENDAS[QT_UNT]),
VENDAS[CODTIPO] = 1
),
0
)

Então Daniel, fiz como mencionou e acontece a mesma coisa. Se eu deixar apenas no nivel Fornecedor na matriz funciona, se eu fazer um drill down não funciona e tras todos departamento/secao/produto não respeitando o relacionamento. Valeu pela atenção.
